# What's the difference between By, and From in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct
Email received by you and Email received from you.

Answer (score 3):

> Email received by you

Someone else sent an email to you. It was received **by** you.

> Email received from you.

You sent an email to someone else. They received it **from** you.

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should consider the verb **RECEIVE**, which is according to Oxford Dictionary and Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary followed by preposition **FROM** when we speak about getting something (examples include: *I received a phone call from your mother; We received an email from the university*)

preposition BY would change the meaning of your sentence, as the phrase **RECEIVED BY** means to be accepted by (examples: *at the end of the century, the revolutionary ideas were received by the government; the prime minister's speech was coldly received by the conference delegates; she was warmly received by her host*)